# How to add /png image and use it as button in C#?

Tags: c#, image, button, cosmos

I am currently creating an OS using Cosmos Kit. I have created the GUI, and now I want to add a menu bar. I have created an image of how it should like but I don't know how to add that image to top-left corner and use it as a button. And secondly, add some text to that.

IMPORTANT:
I don't work in Windows Forms Application, so I only program it.

Thanks, Joe.

Comment: Put the image into a Picture box.  All controls have a click event so a button and a picture box will work exactly the same when click.

Comment: Yeah... Thanks. Anyways, I don't have WFA (Windows Forms Application) so I don't exactly know how am I gonna do that. And I don't know how can I set the listener up for button/picture box.

Comment: How do make a Button that displays a image is dependant 100% on the Display Technology you are using. Windows Forms works totally different from WPF/UWP or ASP.Net. I have no information about that "Cosmo Kit" Display technology. I can not even find it on Wikipedia or Google. A Reference is needed.

Comment: @Christopher https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_(operating_system)  might introduce you Cosmos.

Comment: @Joe: Interesting. Unfortuantely you do not seem to have anything like Windows Forms, WPF or event ASP to support you. You will actually have to write every pixel to the Output yourself. There is no pre-existing button "structure" it seems https://www.gocosmos.org/?s=Button. If anything comes close, it has to be game Development where a lot of work has to go into faking a Desktop like GUI (Buttons, Menus). Some really deep understanding of how Windows Forms or WPF's actuall drawing code works might help too.

Comment: Basically working with Cosmos you appear to be in the Pre OWL/MFC era: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Windows_Library | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library Until someone writes something like the VCL/OWL/MFC, Windows Forms or WPF/UWP Library for Cosmos.